# Troubleshooting a script for my RPI to toggle displays

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, sh, raspbian

So I have a Quimat LCD attached to my gpio.

included is a script which runs to switch to the display (LCD35-show), and another to switch back to the HDMI port (LCD-hdmi). This causes a reboot when done so any variable changes have to happen prior to this.

as this is for my mother who is afraid of touching command prompt, I am trying to set up a single icon to use to switch between video sources.

I am a novice at coding, most of my experience from dabbling in BASIC, and have spent a couple days searching and trying to set this up, but apparently am failing at how to search properly as I couldn't get it functioning.

What I have done so far is this:

Created text file state.txt to hold a variable stating what mode the device is in (HDMI or LCD)

My attempt was to read the variable, then use if then statement to determine which file to run, change the variable then run the file.

This is the code I ended up with.

```
!/bin/bash
read var < state.txt
if var == HDMI
then 
    echo LCD > state.txt
    cd LCD-show/
    sudo ./LCD35-show
else
    echo HDMI > state.txt
        cd LCD-show/
    sudo ./LCD-hdmi
fi
```

I am hoping someone can show me what I did wrong, and hopefully explain what I missed in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your bash script comparisons.
Wrap strings in quotes (or some other method), so it's not a syntax error when string-vars evaluate to *empty*.  You can use `==` for string comparisons in `bash`, but `=` works in `bash` and `sh`.

```
#! /bin/bash
EXE=`basename "$0"`
LCD_DIR="LCD-show"   
STATE_FILE="state.txt"

if [ ! -d "$LCD_DIR" ]; then
    echo "$EXE: $LCD_DIR does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

read var < state.txt  
if [ "$var" = "HDMI" ]; then
    echo LCD > "$STATE_FILE"
    cd "$LCD_DIR"
    sudo ./LCD35-show
else
    echo HDMI > "$STATE_FILE"
    cd "$LCD_DIR"
    sudo ./LCD-hdmi
fi
```

The difference between a good script and a great script is error handling.
What happens when the dir LCD-show does not exist? (for whatever reason).

Comment: So an additional problem, likely my being a noob, but its not working... I try to run and it pops up with 4 options.

[Execute]
[Execute in terminal]
[Open] 
[cancel]
..
Execute in terminal the terminal flashes for half a second, and nothing seems to happen..
Execute, Nothing seems to happen..
Open brings up the text to edit it..
..
BUT 
If i copy/paste into terminal, it seems to work...at least from the hdmi to the lcd...on the way back it hung on the reboot and I had to unplug and replug it, but it did load correctly

Do you have a guess at what i am missing?

Comment: @admini.Strader - It's just finishing and closing the terminal, you could add `echo "Press Enter"; read enter_press` to the last line.  Then it will pause

Comment: Tried that, still got nothing.  Then I tried executing from an already open terminal instead of the gui, and it showed the error message you set up.  Apparently while doing [code] CD /LCD-show [/code] worked in the terminal window I had to change the variable to [code]/home/pi/LCD-show[/code] not sure why it acted differently, or why it didn't show the terminal with the error, but when I did that it now works.     ..    I'd like to make that dialog I mentioned go away, but it works so that's just icing.  Marking as solved, and thanks for helping the noob.

Comment: One last question if you will indulge me. I can see where EXE was called, but dont understand the `basename "$0"  ...what it meant or how it fits.  Just trying to learn and understand.

Comment: @admini.Strader - it's a common convention for a script to print out its name with an error message.  The name of the script is always in `$0`. The `basename` command strips the path off a long filename, so `/path/to/a/file.txt` becomes `file.txt`.  See it's in backticks too, this gets executed in a subshell and evaluated.  So the upshot of all this, is that $EXE becomes a file-name only version of its name.  So if `/path/to/script.sh` was run, $EXE would be `script.sh`

Comment: Good information. I can see how that would be useful for troubleshooting.   I have learned a lot tonight, and thank you for the explanations... is there a way I'm supposed to close the post out or just mark as answer accepted and let it die